# PHP web scraping using div's

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I have tried everything, I have read on the other questions however it doesn't work.

I want from this website:

```
http://www.interparcel.com/tracking.php?action=dotrack&trackno=RE367831140GR
```

To extract this:

> Sorry, no consignment was found with these details.Error - No xml data received

I have also tried with the websites `parcelforce.com` and `dhl.com`: The same procedures, it results zero matches.

Things I have tried (among st many):

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.interparcel.com/tracking.php?action=dotrack&trackno=$nummm');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="header-description">(.*?)</div>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else 
    print "Not found"; 

<?php // File: MatchAllDivMain.php

// Read html file to be processed into $data variable
$data = file_get_contents('test.html');

// Commented regex to extract contents from <div class="main">contents</div>
//  where "contents" may contain nested <div>s.
//  Regex uses PCRE's recursive (?1) sub expression syntax to recurs group 1
$pattern_long = '{           # recursive regex to capture contents of "main" DIV
<div\s+class="main"\s*>              # match the "main" class DIV opening tag
  (                                   # capture "main" DIV contents into $1
    (?:                               # non-cap group for nesting * quantifier
      (?: (?!<div[^>]*>|</div>). )++  # possessively match all non-DIV tag chars
    |                                 # or 
      <div[^>]*>(?1)</div>            # recursively match nested <div>xyz</div>
    )*                                # loop however deep as necessary
  )                                   # end group 1 capture
</div>                               # match the "main" class DIV closing tag
}six';  // single-line (dot matches all), ignore case and free spacing modes ON

// short version of same regex
$pattern_short = '{<div\s+class="main"\s*>((?:(?:(?!<div[^>]*>|</div>).)++|<div[^>]*>(?1)</div>)*)</div>}si';

$matchcount = preg_match_all($pattern_long, $data, $matches);
// $matchcount = preg_match_all($pattern_short, $data, $matches);
echo("<pre>\n");
if ($matchcount > 0) {
    echo("$matchcount matches found.\n");
    //  print_r($matches);
    for($i = 0; $i < $matchcount; $i++) {
        echo("\nMatch #" . ($i + 1) . ":\n");
        echo($matches[1][$i]); // print 1st capture group for match number i
    }
} else {
    echo('No matches');
}
echo("\n</pre>");
?>
```

---

Methods described in:

- http://www.hmp.is.it/scraping-a-site-with-php/
- http://nimishprabhu.com/top-10-best-usage-examples-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html

all without success, any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The data you want is not inside the `div` with class `header-description` but on its parent which is why you can't get it that way.

Comment: That page is missing HTML elements, which in this case, not even using `$dom->recover = true;` it can be recovered, if u look at their HTML you will see its doesn't end.

Comment: @Prix so there is no solution to my problem then :/

Comment: Of course there are, the line you want is the last line on the source code you could simple read the last line and see if it matches to what you're expecting to get, but if the result is anything else you will have to properly handle it and that is specific to that website. The thing is whether that broken HTML is normal output or their server is currently having issues.